# Why does catch not return the error in this case?

Tags: javascript, try-catch

Beginner who just got into Fetch API. I'm trying to `console.log` the error message that appears when someone attempts to fetch a file that doesn't exist but it doesn't work. It only. Can anyone please explain where I'm going wrong.

```
document.getElementById('button1').addEventListener('click', getText);

//getText function
function getText() {
    //fetching file that doesn't exist to produce the error
    fetch('text.text')
    .then(function(response){
        return response.text();
    })
    .then(function(data){
        console.log(data);
    })//what's supposed to happen when the error is caught
    .catch(function(error){
        console.log(error);
    })
}
```

Comment: When you run this on a server that sends back a 404 page, the fetch request hasn't failed, technically. You can however check `response.status === 404`

Comment: @ChrisG - Yeah. One of the worst recent API decisions I've seen. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're running into the [`fetch` footgun](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html) *(that's a post on my anemic little blog)*: `fetch` doesn't reject its promise on HTTP errors, only *network* errors. You have to check for HTTP errors (like 404) yourself. I usually use wrapper functions for that, but here's how to do it with `fetch` directly:

```
function getText() {
    fetch('text.text')
    .then(function(response){
        if (!response.ok) {                                    // ***
            throw new Error("HTTP error " + response.status);  // ***
        }                                                      // ***
        return response.text();
    })
    .then(function(data){
        console.log(data);
    })
    .catch(function(error){
        console.log(error);
    })
}
```

---

FWIW, the wrappers I tend to use are:

```
class FetchError extends Error {
    constructor(response) {
        super(`HTTP error ${response.status}`);
        this.response = response;
    }
}

function fetchJSON(...args) {
    fetch(...args)
    .then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new FetchError(response);
        }
        return response.json();
    });
}

function fetchText(...args) {
    fetch(...args)
    .then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new FetchError(response);
        }
        return response.text();
    });
}

 // ...
```